# "I just got 60 on the quiz" or " I just scored 60 on the quiz" or " I just got 60 in the quiz", are they all good? What's the different?

Tags: word-usage

I just finished an English quiz. It's very hard but I still got 60.

What is the best way to express this?

- I just **got** 60 on the quiz.
- I just **scored** 60 on the quiz.
- I just scored 60 **in** the quiz.

Are they all correct?

Do they have any differences?

Thanks

Comment: If you think you did well, then don't use "just".

Comment: What if I want to say just now? Should I say `I just got 60 on the quiz now` or `I just now got 60 on the quiz` ?

Comment: To emphasize that you received your quiz mark a moment ago, split the sentence into two: I just received my quiz paper. I scored a 60.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your examples might be used by a native speaker.

'Scored' is a better word choice than 'got' as it is more precise, having said that I don't think anyone would misunderstand 'got'.

The word 'just' could either mean 'just now' or 'only just' so it would be better to be clearer about which one you mean.

Comment: so `on` and `in` here are totally the same? Do they have any different meanings? Thanks!

Comment: In this context they are used interchangeably. There are times when they mean different things - for example "The cat sat on the box" and "The cat sat in the box" but in your example both convey the same meaning.